# Get all data of object in Android

Tags: java, android, object, key

I have an object in Java which contains data, I want to collect them all.
Here is an example of what my incomming data is :

[Can find my Object data here](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/oa0qs6/8)

```
            Object[] ret=(Object[])res;
            Map<String, Object> map1 = (Map<String, Object>) ret[0];
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map1.entrySet())
             {
                 System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
             }
```

But this entry.getValue returns me 'java.lang.Object.....' But how can I get the data that's in value? So that I can work with 'M.DEWEER & ...' & the numbers 228 & 229?

Answer (score 1):

By casting the value.  If all values of the same type, say `Integer`, then

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = (Map<String, Integer>) ret[0];
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map1.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }
```

However, according to your linked picture your values are heterogeneous (not all the same):

[image]

The values associated with these keys are `Objects`, but they are objects built from different classes.  To get full access to them you need to cast each based on that class:

- "Id" is an `Integer`
- "partner_id" is something with an `Integer` and a `String`
- "section_id" is something with an `Integer` and a `String`
- "invoice_line" is something with two `Integer`s

I don't know what those classes are since you haven't provided enough information.

If all you wish to do is display the information contained in those classes you can stick with `Object` and use .toString().  The code you posted yourself will work for that if each class has an implementation of .toString() that displays the contents.  If they don't, update them so they do.

If you have control over the collection to be used it might be worth looking into using [A type-safe heterogeneous container "Effective Java Second Edition" by Joshua Bloch](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=josh%20bloch%20heterogeneous%20map&source=bl&ots=yZEkOku5M2&sig=PXXBxIer3cpjGM7CzNLSfaVOhvI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3_b5VJylDsG8ggS8iIOIDw&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=josh%20bloch%20heterogeneous%20map&f=false)

This is all an attempt to avoid using `instanceOf` to detect the type and switching behavior based on that.  This is considered bad practice in Object Oriented Programming because it tends to make code inflexible and difficult to maintain.

Comment: But my Object that I receive consists of  
Map<String, Object> , so I have to find a way to read out the object while I'm reading out an object.

Comment: @TheoJansen you need to find the code that built this map and see for yourself what classes were used to build the objects that make up it's values.